# How do I secure my "hibernate.cfg.xml" file? (Nhibernate)

Tags: .net, security, nhibernate

How do I secure my  "hibernate.cfg.xml" file? (Nhibernate). It currently sits in the route of the web app and can be viewed via the browser.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add verb="*" path="hibernate.cfg.xml"
           type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler"/>
    </httpHandlers>
  </system.web>
<configuration>
```

Comment: BTW, that's exactly what is done by default with *.config files

Answer (score 2):

Your hibernate.cfg.xml should  be set to 'Copy to Output Directory: Copy Always' When you build it it is copied into your output direct. If you publish your site, it will only be in your output (bin) directory so noone will be able to access it.

Comment: Check out: http://nhforge.org/wikis/howtonh/your-first-nhibernate-based-application.aspx 'Add a new xml file to the FirstSolution project and call it hibernate.cfg.xml. Set its property "Copy to Output" to "Copy always".' If you do this then it is read from your bin folder (and protected from being accessed). There is no reason for it to exist anywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

That's a very good question.

There must be a few ways to secure it. One I can think of is - if you are not serving an XML in the web site - to change the MIME type of the XML registered against the web site so that it is not served.

Other solutions not directly securing the "hibernate.cfg.xml" file:

1) Define the configuration in web.config using NHibernate section handler

2) Configure in the code

3) Setup NHibernate to read a file with .config extension

Answer (score 1):

It could live in the bin directory and that way it is protected as well as if if you need to modify it, your app will auto restart as a change was made in the bin directory.

**edit**
you might actually want/have to do this if your nhibernate code lives in a separate class library such that you don't want to mix its configuration in with the web.config (or app.config if sharing the library between interfaces)

Answer (score 0):

Put NHibernate config in web.config, this way it won't be viewed in browsers.

Answer (score 0):

When you publish your website, the first thing you do is to **delete the "hibernate.cfg.xml"** file located in the root folder, so there's no need to secure it

Comment: But the config information is needed so this would break the app right?

Comment: When you build your app, the config file will be made a copy to the bin folder, so the config file located in the root folder is useless now, you can delete it safely.

Answer (score 0):

Put it in your App_Data folder. The App_Data folder is a special protected folder in ASP.NET web applications that can't be externally accessed via a browser. I tend to put all my config files there (except the web.config of course).